# Run Dockerfile command after docker-compose up

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker-compose to build my images and run my services. Now I want to install some dependencies such as GIT and other third party. This is needed to build the application itself because other dependencies of the application pulls its content from git.

I have this as content of my docker-compose.yml

```
web:
  image: nginx:latest
  ports:
    - "9090:80"
  volumes:
    - ./exam:/var/www/html/exam
    - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  links:
    - php
php:
  image: php:7-fpm
  ports:
    - "9000:9000"
  volumes:
    - ./exam:/var/www/html/exam
  links:
    - elk
elk:
  image: sebp/elk
  ports:
    - "5601:5601"
    - "9200:9200"
    - "5044:5044"
```

Now on my Dockerfile I have this

```
FROM php:7-fpm
COPY ./exam /var/www/html/exam
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install git -y
WORKDIR /var/www/html/exam
```

But upon running docker-compose up --build or docker-compose up -d the PHP7-fpm image still doesn't contain any git. Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are building the image from the Dockerhub image, rather than using the local Dockerfile:

remove `image` from `php` section and add `build: .` instead (`.` should be the directory where the `Dockerfile` resides).